Databricks SQL: Execute arithmetic math calculation from a string
For example, I have the arithmetic column on the "calculation" table and I need to multiply that result with the column named Valeu



id
value
arithmetic




1
30
'0.975/24'


2
35
'0.834/24'



Something like:

id 1: '0.975/24' * 30, result = 1.21875

id 2: '0.834/24' * 35, result = 1.21625


I tryed some variations of the query but I keep getting NULL:
with calculation (id, value, arithmetic) AS
(VALUES
   (1,30,'0.975/24'),
   (2,35,'0.834/24')
)
SELECT id, (value * arithmetic) as calc from calculation

databricks-sql result
The pattern used on the arithmetic column can be altered, any suggestions?

Any language that wants to allow something like this will have a function like eval() that does it. Few languages will automatically evaluate strings as expressions (the only exception I know of is bash when evaluating arithmetic expressions, it recursively evaluates variables).

The format of the arithmetic column is always x/y?

The arithmetic can always change, but will always be simple calculations
